# jQuery carousel images with mousewheel support

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [this](http://slobodan.99k.org/coverscroll.html) and [this](http://www.skyplugins.com/sky-jquery-touch-carousel/tooltip_skin.html) jquery plugin and this plugin do not have automatically rotate to left or right and I want to find plugin like these which can rotate automatically with mousewheel support.

I think this plugin do not have this action. Can you help me to create this action or find any plugin with this future?

Comment: Slobodan's scrolls just fine in Chrome on Mac

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [jCarousel lite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/?#demo) offers mouse wheel support.

As does [jQuery.ulSlide](http://jquery-plugins.net/jquery-ulslide-flexible-jquery-slider-carousel-plugin)

Comment: i want to have like http://slobodan.99k.org/coverscroll.html plugin with auto rotate and mouseweel support